# kubernetes-dashboard - authentication

Tags: docker, kubernetes

sorry for my stupid question but I am relatively new in Docker. I have installed Docker and Kubernetes cluster. Also deploy a kubernetes-dashboard. Docker, Kubernetes and all containers are up and running. Locally via kubectl proxy is dashboard available (using wget) but now I need to open dashboard from another computer. I know, that it is about type of authentification, but I really do not know what and where to set. Please, could you help me ? Thank you

Comment: Usually, Kubernetes-dashboard service is running as a NodePort ( In a MiniKube Cluster) then you can access it on the browser with nodeip:nodeport. However, If your cluster is running on cloud, then you need to use loadbalancer type service for k8s-dashboard.  Basically, You need to modify the k8s-dashboard service manifest file to change its accessing behaviour.

Comment: My solution is on-premis (3 workers and 1 master). I can access it, but got error: 


{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
}


it is about wrong authentification but I need help where I can turn it on basic authentification (login, password). Thx

Answer (score 0):

Change the `kubernetes-dashboard` service to `type: NodePort`, then you can access using  NodeIP and service port number.

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above